# Как создать elf с большим количеством сегментов?

Tags: linux, c, ос, elf, системное-программирование

По работе понадобилось пропатчить elf файл так, чтоб в нем было большое количество сегментов. Любой файл,хоть hello world. Какими способами это можно сделать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1088128/4827341

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, этот способ не работает